# is there any way of trasnfering a application running on one system to other system?

Tags: linux, ssh, operating-system

i  want to know is there any way of migrating a application ( say Firefox) from one system to other system ?
 if so please let me know ...

example : suppose i have two systems say A ,B . and Firefox is running in A, now i want to transfer that running application (Firefox) to B as it is

im thinking like, we can migrate the our process stable of the application, why people dnt think in that way, and they simple down marking the question if they dont know the answer? its not the way that we should respond to problem that has been asked in our stack community ... any how people who are good at operating system pleas do think in way that is it possible to transfer our process state to other machine so we can get the same image there at other system .. if so please let me know. thanks in advance..

Comment: Umm, install in on the other machine?

Comment: What actual application do you want to migrate?

Comment: @fedorqui, bmargulies, Athari, Luc M, Mark....im thinking like, we can migrate the our process stable of the application, why people dnt think in that way, and they simple down marking the question if they dont know the answer? its not the way that we should respond to problem that has been asked in our stack community ... any how people who are good at operating system pleas do think in way that is it possible to transfer our process state to other machine so we can get the same image there at other system .. if so please let me know. thanks in advance..

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch , sir im thinking that if i came to know how to migrate a process? its easy to migrate any application. is nt it ? please correct me ..

Comment: It is *practically impossible* to migrate *arbitrary* processes on Linux (and it cannot be easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called [process migration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_migration), and is not easily possible on Linux in general.

However, if you design your application carefully and use some [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) mechanism, it might be possible (in some very limited way). Perhaps using [Berkeley Lab Checkpoint Restart](https://ftg.lbl.gov/projects/CheckpointRestart/) library could help.

Don't expect to migrate processes of applications as complex as Firefox.

Read also about [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) & [virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine). It is relevant. Reading [Queinnec's Lisp in Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) & the famous [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) should also help a lot. See also [Continuation-Passing C](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~kerneis/software/cpc/).

And in practice, you might be able to get process migration for some of your own applications (using few external libraries, or using them "atomically" between checkpoints) if you design your application from the start with process migration in mind.

<sup>PS. Feel free to ask me more e.g. by email, by citing this question, explaining the actual application you want to migrate and what you have read and tried. This subject is surprisingly interesting and difficult (you probably could make a PhD on it).</sup>

Comment: thank you sir. i have red process migration just now briefly, i had doubt how data centers migrating their virtual machines? if we think in way VM aslo a process according to physical sytem. is not it ?